# I want to select data between two dates

Tags: java, sql

```
  SELECT pr_name,
         sub_pr_name,
         SUM(op_bal)AS opb,
         SUM(Inqty)AS inqty1 
    FROM purchasereport 
   WHERE SDate 
 BETWEEN #"+df1.format(from_d)+"# 
     AND #"+df1.format(to_d)+"# 
     AND comp_name='"+cb.getSelectedItem()+"' 
GROUP BY comp_name,pr_name,sub_pr_name
```

**but  it gives results if the  from date is 01 or 02 only .**

Comment: Please add the tag 'sql'.

Comment: Try printing out the SQL query that is produced by this Java statement, and see if you see any issues with it.  Then try running the statement manually on the database and debugging it that way.  One thing to watch out for is that dates are being formatted correctly for the DB.  If this still doesn't help, add the example inputs and sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `SDate 
 BETWEEN #"+df1.format(from_d)+"# 
     AND #"+df1.format(to_d)+"#` into brackets.

Comment: I seriously doubt that this is the problem.

Comment: You have many AND operators. One is for BETWEEN and other for other columns

Comment: Yes, but I believe the statement will be interpreted correctly.